# Using an object in a click event c#

Tags: c#, oop, event-handling

I am using Visual Studio 2010 for C#, I am messing around with some classes and objects before building the application I want to build.

The form I have built has a form1_load event that creates an instance of an object I want to manipulate throughout the form.

When I click a button I want to be able to call one of the methods of my object to execute some statements. I cannot get this to work however, it tells me that the object doesn't exist in the current context, how to I pass this object along to the click event so I can manipulate it?

```
public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyPerson bozo = new MyPerson("bozo",48,23);
        textBox2.Text = bozo.name;
    }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        bozo.myMethod(); // c# is saying that this object doesn't exist in the current context.
    }
```

I understand class structures and objects ok, but I often get stuck on accessing them in different places.

Comment: Read the error message again. It is not about *objects*. It is about *variables* and scope. The `bozo` variable is only in scope in the `Forms1_Load` method because it's a local variable. Using a [*member variable* (aka field)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx) might be the appropriate approach here.

Comment: Add bozo as field of your Form1 class and make it initialization, then you can use this variable

Comment: Ok, that has fixed the problem, I was under the impression making my method type public would allow me to access local variables.

Comment: Is there no way to define an object as a local variable inside a method and then pass it along to a button event for use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your object is a local variable in `Form_Load`, so it exists there only. You could make it a [field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) in the form. For example:

```
private MyPerson bozo { get; set; }

public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bozo = new MyPerson("bozo",48,23);
    textBox2.Text = bozo.name;
}

public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bozo.myMethod(); // now you can access it since it "lives" in the whole form
}
```